# Error: Cannot find control file 'references.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, biber

When I compile my Latex file, I get this error:
`ERROR - Cannot find control file 'references.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?`

Do you have any idea what is the source of this problem ?

P.S.: I have Texstudio as an editor, and in `Options\Configure Texstudio\Commands` I set `biber.exe %` and `bibtex8.exe %` in BibTex and BibTex 8bits boxes, respectively.

Comment: Can you answer the question the message asks? Did you pass the option that way? If not, do so.

Comment: your main file is `references.tex`, right? and your `pdflatex` run was successful?

Comment: @Herbert that is right!

Comment: Actually, it works fine for a list of references I was used before. However, it stops working when I add a new citation, meaning that it cites all the old citations but not the new one.

Comment: @Johannes_B how to do it?

Comment: Put `backend=biber` in the options of package `biblatex`.

Comment: @Johannes_B  I don't have `biblatex` package. I fact, I am using `\documentclass[...]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: @Johannes_B: `backend=biber` is the default of `biblatex`. No need to define it.

Comment: @Herbert Yes, but not if some *template* says `backend=bibtex`. I have seen many of those.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This example works well with `biblatex` and `biber`. Without loading the package, `biber` cannot work.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document} 

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why there is these `\nocite{*}` there?

Comment: @FábioRobertoTeodoro To show all referenced sources in the .bib file. Otherwise only the referenced sources are printed.

Answer (score 27):

Make sure you are using:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

As well as you are building with the command:

```
biber filename
```

And not:

```
biber filename.aux
```

Comment: This is partly covered by the other answer, and seems to be exactly what the OP is doing.

Comment: `backend=biber` is not necessary, as this is the default value.

Answer (score 6):

I also use TeXstudio and I solved the error by going to `Options\Configure Texstudio\Built` and changing `Default Bibliography` Tool from `Biber` to `BibTeX`.

This is similar to what @Alex suggested.

Answer (score 5):

I am using Texmaker 5.0.2 (compiled with Qt 5.9.1) for Mac, and a "style format" from the AEA (https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/templates).

In my case, the solution was extremely simple: go to TexMaker preferences > Commands > there is a small Bib(la)tex space with a file location. In my case this location used to read: 
"/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin/**biber**" %

I changed it to: 
"/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-darwin/**bibtex**" %

and it works perfectly fine. You can navigate to the directory to find other Bib compilers.

I hope this is useful for someone else.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this for several days as I have been trying to meet the NRC requirements for bibliography formatting with the natbib package.  I use TexShop version 3.88 and fixed the problem going to preferences > Engine and changing the BibTex Engine from 'biber' to 'bibtex'.  Thanks for the insight :)