# biber cannot find control file

Tags: bibliographies, biber

I am writing my bachelor thesis and I struggle with creating a proper bibliography.
After having serious problems using bibtex, I have been trying to use biblatex and biber instead, but biber does not create a bibliography at all.
Instead, I get this error message

"INFO - This is Biber 2.2 INFO - Logfile is 'minimal.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'minimal.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1"

Although similar questions have already been asked (e. g. [Error: Cannot find control file 'references.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270599/error-cannot-find-control-file-references-bcf-did-you-pass-the-backend-bi)), the solutions do not help me at all.

I am using TeXLive 2015.

This is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=numeric,
bibencoding=utf8,
natbib=true,
hyperref=true,
sorting=none
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{sourcesMinimal.bib} 

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{hyperref} 
    \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{figure}}
    \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=false,
        allbordercolors={white}}

\begin{document}

test\cite{UniversityofVirginiaSchoolofMedicine.2015}.
test\cite{Yoshie.2004}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and this is the corresponding .bib file:

```
@misc{UniversityofVirginiaSchoolofMedicine.2015,
 author = {{University of Virginia - School of Medicine: Department of Pharmacology}},
 editor = {{University of Virginia - School of Medicine}},
 year = {2015},
 title = {Atomic Force Microscope (AFM)},
 url = {https://pharm.virginia.edu/facilities/atomic-force-microscope-afm/},
 urldate = {2015-09-30}
}


@article{Yoshie.2004,
 author = {Yoshie, T. and Scherer, A. and Hendrickson, J. and Khitrova, G. and Gibbs, H. M. and Rupper, G. and Ell, C. and Shchekin, O. B. and Deppe, D. G.},
 year = {2004},
 title = {Vacuum Rabi splitting with a single quantum dot in a photonic crystal nanocavity},
 pages = {200--203},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {432},
 number = {7014},
 issn = {1476-4687},
 journal = {Nature},
 doi = {10.1038/nature03119}
}
```

Here is the corresponding log file:

```
Package: hobsub-generic 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `etexcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `kvsetkeys' (already loaded).
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package: atbegshi 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen104
\Hy@linkcounter=\count281
\Hy@pagecounter=\count282
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count283
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4443.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4448.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4451.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4458.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4463.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4688.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count284
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5041.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen105
\Fld@menulength=\count285
\Field@Width=\dimen106
\Fld@charsize=\dimen107
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6295.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6300.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6303.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6310.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6315.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6320.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6325.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6365.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6369.
\Hy@abspage=\count286
\c@Item=\count287
\c@Hfootnote=\count288
)
Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count289
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count290
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip62
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `false' on input line 25.
Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support...
Package csquotes Info: ... found 'babel' package.
Package csquotes Info: Adjusting default style.
Package csquotes Info: Redefining alias 'default' -> 'british'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'british'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'british.lbx' found.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/british.lbx
File: british.lbx 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
))
(build/minimal.aux)
\openout1 = `minimal.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 30.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 30.
Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Data encoding 'utf8' specified.
(biblatex) No need to reencode data.
\openout3 = `minimal.bcf'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'minimal.bbl' not found.
No file minimal.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 30.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 30.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count291
\scratchdimen=\dimen108
\scratchbox=\box27
\nofMPsegments=\count292
\nofMParguments=\count293
\everyMPshowfont=\toks18
\MPscratchCnt=\count294
\MPscratchDim=\dimen109
\MPnumerator=\count295
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count296
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks19
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box28
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 30.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count297
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 30.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 30.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 30.
(build/minimal.out) (build/minimal.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `minimal.out'.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'UniversityofVirginiaSchoolofMedicine.2015' on page 1 u
ndefined on input line 32.
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Yoshie.2004' on page 1 undefined on input line 34.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 36.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 38.
[1
{c:/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 38.
(build/minimal.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 38.
*File List*
scrreprt.cls 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (report)
scrkbase.sty 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
scrbase.sty 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent
basics and keyval usage)
keyval.sty 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
inputenc.sty 2015/03/17 v1.2c Input encoding file
utf8.def 2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
t1enc.dfu 2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
ot1enc.dfu 2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
omsenc.dfu 2015/09/07 v1.1p UTF-8 support for inputenc
fontenc.sty
t1enc.def 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
babel.sty 2015/08/03 3.9m The Babel package
english.ldf 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system
csquotes.sty 2015/07/18 v5.1f context-sensitive quotations (JAW)
etoolbox.sty 2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
csquotes.def 2015/07/18 v5.1f csquotes generic definitions (JAW)
csquotes.cfg
biblatex.sty 2015/10/21 v3.1 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty 2015/10/21 v3.1 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
kvoptions.sty 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
ltxcmds.sty 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
logreq.sty 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
ifthen.sty 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
url.sty 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
blx-dm.def
numeric.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def
blx-natbib.def 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
standard.bbx 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
numeric.bbx 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
numeric.cbx 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg
xcolor.sty 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
hyperref.sty 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty 2012/05/28 v1.13 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
hobsub.sty 2012/05/28 v1.13 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifvtex.sty 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
intcalc.sty 2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
ifpdf.sty 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty 2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty 2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
bitset.sty 2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty 2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty 2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
hopatch.sty 2012/05/28 v1.2 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty 2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty 2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty 2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty 2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
hycolor.sty 2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
ifxetex.sty 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
auxhook.sty 2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
pd1enc.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
hpdftex.def 2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty 2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
english.lbx 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
british.lbx 2015/10/21 v3.1 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
supp-pdf.mkii
nameref.sty 2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty 2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
minimal.out
```

If you could help me, this would be the best Christmas present this year!

Problem was solved by avoiding an extra output folder (see comments)

Comment: is the missing comma after `bibencoding=utf8` a typo or is it also in your document?

Comment: It was also in my document, but adding it does not fix the problem

Comment: @brick91 Trash all the auxiliary files and start over with the compile chain.

Comment: @Johannes_B This does not change the error message

Comment: [Texstudio + Biber + build folder](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184204)

Comment: The log-file shows that the bcf is written: `\openout3 = minimal.bcf`. So check if it exist and *where* it is. And then check if biber actually starts in the folder of the bcf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this test document and tell us if it works.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib,hyperref,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\begin{document}
foo\nocite{*}   
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: It produces the same error message

Comment: post the output of the `biber` run and the the auxiliary file of the pdflatex run. I suppose that you have no write access in your working directory.

Comment: This is my biber output: Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.2 INFO - Logfile is 'minimal.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'minimal.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: and this is the aux-file:

Comment: \relax 
\providecommand\hyper@newdestlabel[2]{}
\abx@aux@sortscheme{none}
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}
\fi}

Comment: \global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToCoFields[2]{}
\abx@aux@cite{UniversityofVirginiaSchoolofMedicine.2015}
\abx@aux@cite{Yoshie.2004}
\@writefile{toc}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lof}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }

Comment: \@writefile{lot}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\select@language{british}
\@writefile{toc}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{british}}
\@writefile{lof}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{british}}
\@writefile{lot}{\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax }\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{british}}

Comment: Is this file in your main documents directory or do you have an own directory for the help/log files?

Comment: `(build/minimal.aux)`