# Error Message in Compilation with glossaries and natbib Packages

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, glossaries, compilation-error, glossary

I have a simple .tex file where I would like to use the `glossaries` and `natbib` packages for a glossary and a bibliography. The minimal working example (MWE) and the document build  are given below.

**MWE**

```
% pdflatex 
% makeglossaries  
% pdflatex 
% bibtex
% pdflatex 
% pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

% Palatino font 
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
   
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
pdffitwindow=false,
colorlinks=true, 
linkcolor=blue, 
citecolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue,
breaklinks=true,
hypertexnames=false,
bookmarksnumbered=true
}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[numbers, sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

% Glossary
\usepackage[nopostdot,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\glsdisablehyper 
\makeglossaries 

\newglossaryentry{ex}{name={sample},description={an example}}
\setacronymstyle{long-sc-short}
\newacronym{svm}{svm}{support vector machine}
\renewcommand*{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textmd{#1}}

\begin{document}
First use: \gls{svm}. Second use: \gls{svm}. 
Here's my \gls{ex} term. 
Soliton is an entity~\cite{Soliton}.

% Bibliography  
\bibliography{references}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The .bib is given below.

```
@article{Soliton,
title = {Observation and analysis of multiple dark-antidark solitons in two-component {B}ose-{E}instein condensates},
author = {Katsimiga, G. C. and Mistakidis, S. I. and Bersano, T. M. and Ome, M. K. H. and Mossman, S. M. and Mukherjee, K. and Schmelcher, P. and Engels, P. and Kevrekidis, P. G.},
journal = {Phys. Rev. A},
volume = {102},
issue = {2},
pages = {023301},
numpages = {11},
year = {2020},
month = {Aug},
publisher = {American Physical Society},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevA.102.023301},
url = {https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.102.023301}
}
```

**The Issue**

The issue is once I compile the following error message is shown. However, the document is built properly. I am wonder why does this happen and how can I prevent the error?

**The Error Message**

```
Process started: biber "print_glossary_bib"

Use of uninitialized value in quotemeta at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/Config.pm line 228.
Use of uninitialized value $tool in concatenation (.) or string at 
/usr/share/perl5/Biber/Config.pm line 307.
INFO - This is Biber 2.17
INFO - Logfile is 'print_glossary_bib.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'print_glossary_bib.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
Process exited with error(s)


Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "print_glossary_bib".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: makeglossaries "print_glossary_bib"

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "print_glossary_bib".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: bibtex "print_glossary_bib".aux

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian)
The top-level auxiliary file: print_glossary_bib.aux
The style file: unsrtnat.bst
Database file #1: references.bib
Process exited normally



Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "print_glossary_bib".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "print_glossary_bib".tex

Process exited normally
```

However, if I recompile (using the whole build sequence), then this second time, there is no error message displayed!

Comment: biber should be used with biblatex, not with natbib. There you need bibtex.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I found that the Default Bibliography Tool was set to `biber` in TeXstudio. I then changed it to `bibtex` and that resolved the issue.

Comment: A similar problem is also resolved here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650895/37044
) in the same way.